# How do you override/remove default completions in fish shell?

Tags: fish

I am adding completions for a command's subcommand, however fish is retaining the built in completions for the base command, but those no longer apply for the subcommand. I want to disable those base command completions when using the subcommand.

So, to give a specific example, I am adding `complete` completions for the `python3 -m venv` command. As I stated, all the builtin `python3` completions still show even though they no longer apply. So, when I type `python3 -m venv -<TAB>`, I get the completions I've added (good!), but also all the default completions too (bad).

So I have this code:

```
function __fish_python_using_command
    # make sure that the command (minus the first item) matches argv
    set cmd (commandline -opc)
    if [ (count $cmd) -le (count $argv) ]
        return 1
    end
    set idx (math (count $argv)+1)
    if [ "$argv" = "$cmd[2..$idx]" ]
        return 0
    end
    return 1
end

complete -f -c python3 -n '__fish_python_using_command -m venv' -s h -l help -d 'Display help creating virtual Python environments'
```

After running this, when I type when I type `python3 -m venv -<TAB>` I get:

- The new auto complete I defined for `--help` (correct)
- The base defined auto complete for `-h` (wrong)
- All the other `python3` base auto complete switches like `-V` from `complete --command python3 --short-option 'V' --description 'Display version and exit'` (I want to disable these)

I have considered using the `-e` flag to remove the defaults when you are in `python3 -m venv` mode, but that seems like the wrong way to go about it. I'm stumped. How would one disable all existing completions once a subcommand mode is entered? Or would this require a fundamental change to the way the `python3` fish builtin completions are structured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fish loads completions from files in $fish_complete_path. This is a list of directories, like $PATH. Put your completions into a file named after the command with a ".fish" suffix in an earlier directory and it will take precedence.

E.g. ~/.config/fish/completions/python3.fish.

Comment: This works, but then I lose all the built-in completions. I assume I have to copy the built-ins into my python3.fish completions file for this to get me where I want to be, right? Still, this isn't a terrible way to go even if this turns out to be the best answer. Thanks! This is probably going to turn into me submitting a PR to the fish project with better python3 completions, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you'd either copy the builtin ones or `source` them from yours.